# how to change to proper directory

Tags: python, csv, directory

I'm importing a csv file onto my script and its saying that there's no such file or directory.

I've copied the csv file onto the directory of my script.

```
import csv

with open("PycharmProject/untitled/sitka_weather_07-2014.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
```

errno 2 occurs for all of my attempts

Comment: Which directory is your Python script in?

Comment: Share your directory structure including the Python script file and CSV file.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a leg here and say that the url should just be `"untitled/sitka_weather_07-2014.csv"`, I'm guessing that your python script is inside  `PycharmProject`

Comment: the directory is in "/Users/user1/PycharmProjects/untitled". I downloaded the CSV file to my IDE (PyCharm) and went to "save as" and saved it to the same directory. still the same error